# First time setup by checking the database in Android SDK

Tags: android

My application will show a first time setup screen when the user opens it for the first time. I need to know when it is the first time the application is executed and my question is:

Should I do this by checking and changing a flag setting in `SharedPreferences` or is it more secure to check if the database is empty (I use `SQLiteOpenHelper`)?
In the last case, how can I check if the database is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharedPreferences will most likely be quicker, but if you want to check for an empty database:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME", null);
if (cursor != null){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor.getInt(0) == 0) {
      // It is Empty 
    }
}
```

where `TABLE_NAME` is the name of a table (that should be populated) in your database.
The only concern I have with the database is if you end up changing what and when something is populated, potentially resulting in the app failing to know the correct time to show the set-up screen - a single boolean `SharedPreferences` flag might be simpler.